# X is an hyperplane iff it is a maximal non spanning set

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, matroids, algebraic-combinatorics

URGENT
I'm trying to show that $X$ is an hyperplane iff it is a maximal non-spanning set. If I assume that $X$ is an hyperplane, I know that it must be of $rk(M)-1$ (with $M$ a matroid), so it follows directly that it's a non-spanning set. However, I'm struggling with the proof of its maximality.
For the other implication, if it's a non-spanning set, then we have $r(X)<r(M)$, but I need to prove (I think with maximality) that the rank it's $r(X)-1$, such that it can be an hyperplane.

**EDIT**

The question is from the book named "Matroid Theory" by James Oxley, second edition, section 4, chapter 1.

Comment: What do you mean by 'hyperplane' in the matroid context?

Comment: I saw that an hyperplane is a flat of rank $r(M)-1$ (called also maximal flat I think)

Comment: If a set is maximal with some property, then it can't have elements added to it and retain the property. Try adding elements to your set and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

If $H$ is a hyperplane, then it is a flat of rank $r(H)=r(M)-1$.
Assume $H$ is a hyperplane, then it is non-spanning as $r(H)<r(M)$ and suppose its not maximal, so $H\subset H'$ such that $r(H')<r(M)$ but, because $H$ is flat, if $a\in H'\setminus H$ then $r(H\cup \{a\})=r(H)+1=r(M)$ which is a contradiction, so $H$ is maximal.
Suppose $H$ is non-spanning and maximal. We have that $H\subseteq cl(H)$, so if $H\subset cl(H)$, and we know $r(H)=r(cl(H))<r(M)$ then $cl(H)$ is non-spanning, so $H$ wouldn't be maximal. This implies that $H$ is a flat. Suppose that $r(H)<r(M)-1$, then for $a\not \in H$ $r(H\cup \{a\})<r(M)$ because $H$ is flat, and this contradicts maximality too, hence $r(H)=r(M)-1$ and so $H$ is a hyperplane.

Comment: @Emptymind Indeed, thanks.